# Why is the Int immutable?

Tags: ios, swift

I have an NSDictionary, and there is an array within it composed of integers, and I am trying to change an integer at a certain index. I am getting this error though `Cannot assign to immutable expression of type Int`

```
var avafdg = object["Availability"] as? NSDictionary //I am importing the Dictionary from Parse, and it is imported correctly.
avafdg![0]![12] as! Int = 1 // I get the error here
```

Comment: Free tips: 1- Use NSMutableDictionary. 2- Actually, don't: use a Swift dictionary instead of Foundation's classes. 3- Don't force unwrap, use safe code like `if let`. 4- Don't use a dictionary like an array. Use an array if you need one.

Comment: `as! Int` tells the compiler to force cast the *result* of the subscript – therefore it makes no sense to try and assign in that statement. Get rid of the forced downcast, and then do everything that Eric says above – you should only ever be using an `NSDictionary` in Swift as a means of interfacing with Objective-C (which can be done implicitly anyway – you rarely have to ever use it directly). Once you're back in Swift land, bridge it back to a Swift collection.

Comment: I took down the forced downcast, but now I get `Cannot assign to immutable expression of type AnyObject`

Comment: @manatee That'll be because the compiler doesn't know that `avafdg[0]` is an `NSMutableDictionary/Array` therefore won't allow you to try and set through it – and this is the exact reason why you should be using the native Swift collection types here... why aren't you?

Comment: Split `avafdg![0]![12] as! Int` into multiple expressions and you will see why the value is not mutable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot assign to a result of operator `as!`. Subscript `[]` operator of a `Dictionary` is tricky in that when you write

```
avafdg![123] = 456
```

Swift knows to call an update method to process this assignment. However, once you do a cast, the assignment is no longer possible. In fact, it no longer makes sense, for the same reason as an assignment to the result of, say, an addition operation, would be meaningless:

```
x+5 = 6 // <<== Will not compile
```

Fortunately, you do not need to cast to an `Int` in order to store a new `Int` into your dictionary. You need to tell Swift that whatever is returned by the first indirection is a `NSMutableDictionary`<sup>*</sup>, too:

```
var innerDictionary = avafdg![0] as NSMutableDictionary!
innerDictionary[12] = 1
```

<sup>*</sup> I am assuming that it is `NSMutableDictionary`, but it could be `NSMutableArray` as well, depending on the data structure that you have.

Comment: If I have a bigger NSDictionary, and I need to insert this in there, how would I do that. My current solution is `avafdgtest![5] as! NSMutableArray = innerDictionary` but I get the same error as above with respect to NSMutableArray.

Comment: @manatee The cast has to be in parentheses, and the assignment has to be done directly to the result of `[]` operator. Try `(avafdgtest![5] as! NSMutableArray)[12] = 1`